# COM .NET DLL not registering in the GAC (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

Tags: c#, .net, com, ole, gac

I built a .net COM dll (debug x64) on one machine. I have it all setup and working there (I can see it in C:\Windows\Micorosft.NET\assembly and OLEVIEWER).

I took the dll to another machine (along with it's .h and .c file generated from MIDL). I register the dll into the GAC by following these steps http://codeingaddiction.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-add-strong-name-to-existing-dll_16.html - create key pair, generate MISL, rebuild assembly from MISL with the key, and then adding it to the GAC. It seems to be in the GAC, and I can try searching for it with gacutil /l MyDllName. However, in my client application, when I link against it, at run time when invoking `CoCreateInstance` I get `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` (HRESULT). I can't see the dll in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET/Assembly nor in OLEVIEW.

Have I missed out any steps, or done something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You never mentioned using Regasm.exe to register the assembly.  You can skip that on your dev machine when you use the project's "Register for COM interop" checkbox.  Not on the user's machine of course.  Using MIDL is pretty strange btw, that does not sound kosher.

Comment: if not using MIDL (as the tutorial at http://codeingaddiction.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-add-strong-name-to-existing-dll_16.html shows), what is the "kosher" way of doing it? (btw my gut thought using MIDL was a bit hacky)

Comment: You'd normally use the #import directive in a C++ program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` is because your .net COM DLL is not registered. Any .net assembly needs to be registered for it to be exposed as a com class to the clients. We need to use `regasm.exe` to register the .net assembly.

Comment: That's got me further. I still can't see the assembly under Type Libraries in OLEVIEW (I can on the machine where I built the COM dll). Also when I try invoking a method on the interface from my client application on my target machine I get " ... has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations."

Comment: This is because the type library of the assembly is not registered. You can register it by adding /tlb parameter to the regasm.exe like "regasm myTest.dll /tlb:myTest.tlb". The previous command registers myTest.dll and also generates and registers the type library myTest.tlb.